# .pdb file viewer or reader tools?

Tags: database, viewer, palm

I have a lot of files in `.pdb` (as in a [Palm Pilot Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDB_%28Palm_OS%29)) format, major of them downloaded, but until now I can't using or read what the inside, so I looking for how to read, view the .pdb file format from MS Windows XP.

Any converter or viewer tools as free download you know?

For any input would be help me.

Comment: What sort of files are they? Do you remember? What "apps" opened them? Were they ebooks?

Answer (score 1):

My [Palm Pilot converter](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/pilot/pdb/) understands just a few of the native database formats.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is **[calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/)** the one stop solution to all your e-book needs, you can use **calibre** to view or convert PDB files, it has a built-in ebook viewer that can display all the major ebook formats. It has full support for Table of Contents, bookmarks, CSS, a reference mode, printing, searching, copying, customizing the rendering via a user style sheet, embedded fonts, etc.

Input Formats:

> CBZ, CBR, CBC, EPUB, FB2, HTML, LIT,
>   LRF, MOBI, ODT, PDF, PRC, **PDB**,
>   PML, RB, RTF, TCR, TXT

The calibre e-book viewer can now view *all* the e-book formats that calibre can convert.

[image]

*Calibre is freeware, available for Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.*

Edit: maybe you can use the **[Palm OS Emulator](http://www.tucows.com/preview/261443)** to open the files.

Comment: well thank for your nice input, but unfortunately Calibre can not solve my case...

Comment: @jones - updated my post.

Comment: Ok friend... i will try it, thank so far for your contribution...

Comment: Calibre doesn't read Palm DB files... Only PDB files that are eBooks. Some examples of Calibre errors: "Identity is DATAnpad. Book type is Unknown" or "- Unknown.pdb with error: InputFormatPlugin: PDB Input running".

Answer (score 0):

Two free utilities that might solve your problem.

[**DB-Editor**](http://db-editor.en.softonic.com/palm)

> DB-Editor is a graphical user
>   interface that lets you edit and
>   create databases for Pilot-DB under MS
>   Windows.
>
> Capabilities:
>
> - Excel sheet import, without installed    Excel
> - Import from CSV files
> - Create file lists of your local directories having various filter
>     possibilities
> - Create a file list of your MP3 collection including MP3 tags
> - Import from JFile, and ListDB
> - Export your database to a MS Word file
> - Export to a Excel sheet, without installed Excel
> - Export to plain ASCII file
> - Export to XML
> - Export to CSV
> - Export to HTML using CSS
>
> DB-Editor is Freeware and a beta
>   version.

[**Pilot-DB**](http://pilot-db.sourceforge.net/)

> Pilot-DB is a freeware (OpenSource)
>   database program for the Palm OS (any
>   version and any hardware) and compares
>   with the best commercial programs
>   available.
>
> It supports the field types string,
>   boolean, integer, float, calculated,
>   date, time, note, list and link.
>
> Plug-Ins are available for Mobile-DB
>   and JFile databases, for access to the
>   built-in DateBook, for external memory
>   card access and for customizable
>   colours.
>
> Overlays are available for various
>   occidental and oriental languages
>
> There are various third-party tools to
>   create, edit, and export PilotDB-files
>   or to import various formats such as
>   CSV, Excel, ASCII files and Staroffice
>   files on the desktop:

**EDIT**

[Kernel for PDB](http://www.palmpilotdatarecovery.com/) (commercial $49.95, demo available)
Palm Database Recovery Software that can save all files or folders structures.

Comment: Thank harrymc, for your suggestions, but unfortunately it can not open/view/convert my .pdb file

Comment: @harrymc - OT: if you 'format' your comment accordingly (@jones) he will be notified.

Comment: @jones: I've added one more.

Comment: @Molly: Thanks. I thought up till now that the poster is always notified of all changes.

Answer (score 0):

If they are e-books, chances are that they are in WeaselReader (GutenPalm) zTXT format. You can check it out by opening the .pdb with Notepad or MFC Wordpad and verifying that near the beginning there's the string **`zTXTGPlm`**.

Then the utility `makeztxt` in "deconstruct" mode can get you back the .txt original.

Otherwise, you might try with the [CPAN ZTxt module](http://search.cpan.org/~rudy/Palm-Ztxt-0.90/Ztxt.pm).